# jQuery no PhoneGap não funciona depois que gera APK

Tags: android, apache-cordova, cordova-plugin, phonegap-buillder

Testei jQuery somente o comando

```
iniciar_cadastro: function(){
       window.location = 'cadastro.html';
    }
};
```

Apertando um botão, ele funciona no quando coloco PhoneGap serve testando no celular, mas quando gero APK teste com o comando `cordova build android`, ele não não funciona.

Comment: Aonde você está fazendo o uso do **jQuery** nesse código ?

Comment: olha la embaixo o que vou colocar a imagem

Comment: voce olhou a imagem

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a imagem abaixo dos mesmo arquivos www